# finding the count of cells in a given 2d array satisfying the given constraints

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, counting

Given a 2-D array starting at (0,0) and proceeding to infinity in positive x and y axes. Given a number k>0 , find the number of cells reachable from (0,0) such that at every moment -> sum of digits of x+ sum of digits of y <=k  . Moves can be up, down ,left or right. given x,y>=0 . 
 Dfs gives answers but not sufficient for large values of k. anyone can help me with a better algorithm for this?

Comment: In `sum of digits of x+ sum of digits of y`, what exactly are `x` and `y`?

Comment: x and y are coordinates at a particular moment and we always start from (0,0)

Comment: it depends on one's solution till what extent of k it can solve. dfs does it for very less.. i probably want to know the best possible one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think they asked you to calculate the number of cells (x,y) reachable with k>=x+y. If x=1 for example, then y can take any number between 0 and k-1 and the sum would be <=k. The total number of possibilities can be calculated by

```
sum(sum(1,y=0..k-x),x=0..k) = 1/2*k²+3/2*k+1
```

That should be able to do the trick for large k.

I am somewhat confused by the "digits" in your question. The digits make up the index like 3 times 9 makes 999. The sum of digits for the cell (999,888) would be 51. If you would allow the sum of digits to be 10^9 then you could potentially have 10^8 digits for an index, resulting something around 10^(10^8) entries, well beyond normal sizes for a table. I am therefore assuming my first interpretation. If that's not correct, then could you explain it a bit more?

**EDIT**:

okay, so my answer is not going to solve it. I'm afraid I don't see a nice formula or answer. I would approach it as a coloring/marking problem and mark all valid cells, then use some other technique to make sure all the parts are connected/to count them.

I have tried to come up with something but it's too messy. Basically I would try and mark large parts at once based on the index and k. If k=20, you can mark the cell range (0,0..299) at once (as any lower index will have a lower index sum) and continue to check the rest of the range. I start with 299 by fixing the 2 last digits to their maximum value and look for the max value for the first digit. Then continue that process for the remaining hundreds (300-999) and only fix the last digit to end up with 300..389 and 390..398. However, you can already see that it's a mess... (nevertheless i wanted to give it to you, you might get some better idea)

Another thing you can see immediately is that you problem is symmetric in index so any valid cell (x,y) tells you there's another valid cell (y,x). In a marking scheme / dfs/ bfs this can be exploited.

Comment: the question was for sum of digits of x + sum of digits of y <= k . also the interviewer didn't tell me the actual constraints but wanted me to give the best algorithm that could cover as large values as it could.

Comment: and how do the moves come in? Suppose k=2, then cell(10,10) is valid but you cannot reach it with moves. Does there need to be a path?

Comment: yes so that doesn't need be in the answer. the past must contain each cell satisfying the condition.